# Book for children: the winning knight of a tournament is rewarded with a wish and he wishes that the dragons must not be killed

Tags: story-identification, dragons, medieval

I do not know the book, but a young argentinian girl has asked for it on reddit and I want to help her.

Her book description is as follows. She readed the book in spanish, but may be a translation from another language. I apologize for the slightly childish style.

> It is in the middle ages, there is a tournament of jousting each year
>   and the knight who wins the tournament is granted a wish that
>   remains valid until the tournament the following year
>
> There are dragons but they are disappearing because they are killed because people thinks they are bad
>
> Then a feudal lord, very skinny and weak, knows a dragon, and the dragon tells him that they are being killed
>
> Then the dragon convinces him to participate in the tournament and ask as a wish that dragons not be killed for a year
>
> And the dragon trains him so he can win
>
> And in the tournament he has to fight with a feudal lord who is big and bad and loves to kill dragons
>
> In the end the skinny wins.
>
> But the book leaves in doubt what happens the following year
>
> I think there was a girl or a princess
>
> I believe that the king granted the desire

https://www.reddit.com/r/es/comments/6x9d8r/me_ayudan_a_identificar_este_libro/

Comment: You needn't apologize for the childish style!

Comment: @HarryWeasley Oh, I just wanted you to take me seriously! ;)

Comment: I take it that you didn't read it yourself?

Comment: And are you sure it was a translation?

Comment: This might help me find out what the book is!

Comment: @HarryWeasley I translated and quoted the girl's question as faithfully as I could. She did not remember if this story was originally written in spanish or translated from another language

Comment: Okay, not knowing Spanish myself, I need your help! Any information on whether it was a comic or a story? Though, since you yourself didn't read it, you mightn't know! Thanks!

Comment: There are too many stories involving dragons and knights!

Comment: @HarryWeasley It was a book, and the girl remembers that it had black and white illustrations. Thanks for your interest.